# Pulverize not working, PHP Notices

Tags: rendering, scripting, add-on, video-sequence-editor

So, I realized that Blender was not using all of my CPU processing power with a Ryzen 5 2600X, it only uses 10 % max.

So I downloaded [Pulverize](https://github.com/sciactive/pulverize) with PHP, FFmpeg and Python. When attempting to run a render with the script, I faced a couple error messages in the Command Prompt.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the question is about a script specifically for Blender, so there I see a relation to Blender. I believe there could be a few people around here utilizing third party scripts for Blender that might help the asker.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding